# Conditional statement doesn't work in node.html.twig

Tags: theming, 8

I want to use `{% if %}` in a node.html.twig, but it doesn't work.

I am using this code.

```
{% if content.field_number == 0 %}
  zero
{% else %}
  one
{% endif %}
```

It always print *one*.

The following code always print *zero*.

```
{% if content.field_number %}
  zero
{% else %}
  one
{% endif %}
```

What code should I use to *zero* when the field contains zero?

Comment: What is the actual value of _content.field_number_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`content.field_number` is the rendered output and the value of the field is somewhere inside the render array, for example in a `#markup`. But this will change whenever someone reconfigures the view mode.

It is better to use the node object in this case, because the field value will be available for all view mode configurations:

```
{% if node.field_number.value %}
  not zero
{% else %}
  zero
{% endif %}
```