# Testing field value in twig template

Tags: 8, theming

In my twig theme - I'm attempting to test the value of the field "field_left_image_front" - which is either "Yes" or "No"

```
{% if content.field_left_image_front.0 == "Yes"  %}
<img class="content-image" src="{{ file_url(content.field_left_image.0['#item'].entity.uri.value) }}">
{% else %}
<div class="textdescriptions" style="background-color:{{ content.field_left_hex_color.0 }}"><!--start text descriptions-->
<div class="textdetails" style="color:white !important"> <!--start text details-->
<h1>{{ content.field_left_title.0 }} {{ content.field_left_image_front.0 }}</h1>
<p>{{ content.field_left_body }}</p>
</div><!--end text details-->
</div>
{% endif %}
```

A few bits of info:

1. field_left_image_front is a select list/list item in the CMS
2. I'm testing the value by outputting it in h1 tag - so I can see that it's "Yes"
3. Despite being "Yes", it's outpitting the text description and ignoring the image.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the conditional?

Comment: This is something I would just preprocess for the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `node` (if this is a node template) to get the field value, see [Conditional statement doesn't work in node.html.twig](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198124/conditional-statement-doesnt-work-in-node-html-twig). Another reason in this case is that Yes/No would be translatable in a multilingual site, while the field value from `node`is the untranslatable left key of a select list.

If it is not a node template look at the variables listed at the top of the template, for example paragraph.html.twig:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a paragraph.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - paragraph: Full paragraph entity.

 * - content: All paragraph items. Use {{ content }} to print them all,
 *   or print a subset such as {{ content.field_example }}. Use
 *   {{ content|without('field_example') }} to temporarily suppress the printing
 *   of a given child element.
```

Here the variable for the entity is `paragraph` and for the render array `content`.

So use `{{ content.field_example }}` to print fields and `{{ paragraph.field_example.value }}` to get field values from the database.

Comment: (this is probably outside the scope of the original question - but I'll ask anyway since I'm new to themeing) - 

I would have attempted to use a node variable - but the file is actually a paragraph twig file (paragraph--front-style-one.html.twig).  I was under the impression that node variables weren't available in there - which is why everything was set up as 

content.field_whatever_.0

Am I right that node variables aren't accessible there - and that you'd have to add them via pre-preprocessing?  Or no?

Comment: You could get the node, even from the twig template with getParentEntity(), but this would be off topic, because you can put paragraphs in other entities like users or blocks, or nest them in other paragraphs. If you have a paragraph template then use `paragraph`, see the edited answer.