# How can I embed a view in a template when passing view name and parameters are passed as variables?

Tags: views, 8, theming

Inside my paragraph template I have variables which contain category id and view machine name. So when I print them like this:

```
  {{ content.field_category }}
  {{ content.field_view }}
```

I get correct values.

Then I'm using twig tweak to embed view and if I embed it with hard-coded values, like this:

```
  {{ drupal_view('view_machine_name', 'embed_1', 33) }}
```

it also works. I hard-coded the same values my variables display from above.

Now I want to use my field values instead of hard-coded values:

```
{{ drupal_view(content.field_view, 'embed_1', content.field_category) }}
```

I get error like:

```
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadMultiple() (line 266 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php). Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->load() (line 251 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php).
```

when I try to replace view parameter and:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Placeholders must have a trailing [] if they are to be expanded with an array of values. in Drupal\Core\Database\Connection->expandArguments() (line 738 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Connection.php).
```

When I try to replace category parameter.

I guess that `content.field_category` is not an int value and `content.field_view` is not an string, as this twig filter expects but I have no idea how to convert them to those primitive types?

Tried `intval` - it's not working

Tried `number_format` - also not working

I guess I would have to somehow get view machine name and category id directly from those objects but I don't know how to achieve that.

Tried `content.field_category.id()` and `content.field_view.id()`

Nothing works.

Comment: What template exactly? Enable Twig Debugging, install the Devel sub-module Kint and then put `{{ kint() }}` in your template for having all available variables pretty-printed on screen and inspect them. It probably needs to be `{{ content.field_view.value }}` or `{{ content.field_view.0 }}` (same for the cat field) for printing your field values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/228388/15055

Comment: You can't pass the render arrays, you need to pass the raw values.

Comment: `{{ drupal_view(content.field_view, 'embed_1', content.field_category.0) }}`

Comment: For a paragraph template see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/263285/47547

Comment: Before reading this comments I managed somehow to get raw values with content.field_category['#items'][0].getValue()['target_id']. I actually have 2 parameters, with 2 vocabularies (wanted to simplify situation). Now I tried and for one category field .0 works and for other .value works, even setup is the same for both?!? Template is override of basic paragraph.html.twig template. Thank you all for help!

Comment: Update ".0" was not working, but just not crushing, since I wrote badly field name, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid using `{{ content }}` this way. The position you have found in the render array in your last [comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/292794/how-can-i-embed-a-view-in-a-template-when-passing-view-name-and-parameters-are-p#comment368380_292794) can change anytime when reconfiguring the paragraph type or when installing/updating code. Render arrays are not APIs and they are only required to have valid renderable child elements at the lowest level, but not a fixed structure.

The Entity API on the other hand, which you would use to access `{{ paragraph }}` in a paragraph template, does not change, at least not without a transition period while you can still use a deprecated API.

Example:

```
// field value like string or number
{{ paragraph.field_example.value }}

// target id of a reference field
{{ paragraph.field_reference.target_id }}
```

See also https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/263285/47547.

Comment: Great! This works like a charm. I don't know is it me or things like this are hard to find... :/