# How to pass a field value as contextual filter argument using Twig Tweak drupal_view?

Tags: 8, theming

In Drupal 8, I'm using Twig Tweak to embed a view. I have a contextual filter set to one of the node's fields, `field_project_id`. If I use a literal for the third argument, it works. If I try to reference the value of the current node's project ID, no luck.

Works:

```
{{ drupal_view('my_view', 'block_1', '2011-40054-000') }}
```

Doesn't work:

```
{{ drupal_view('my_view', 'block_1', content.field_project_id) }},  
{{ drupal_view('my_view', 'block_1', content.field_project_id.value) }},  
{{ drupal_view('my_view', 'block_1', content.field_project_id.0) }},  
{{ drupal_view('my_view', 'block_1', content.field_project_id.0.value) }},
```

etc.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: What type is _field_project_id_?

Comment: Is this a node template?

Comment: _field_project_id_ is Text (plain) and yes, this is a node template.

Comment: Then use the node object `node.field_project_id.value`. `{{ content }}` is for rendering and `node` is for coding, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198124/conditional-statement-doesnt-work-in-node-html-twig

Answer (score 0):

First of all check `drupal_view` implementation but I think that the arguments parameter (contextual filters) is an array, though the function wraps scalars into an array you should pass an array (robustness). Said that everything looks fine in your template perhaps you should do `{{ vardumper(content) }}`  to see what actually is getting to your template variable. In order to use the **vardumper** function you need to install the [VarDumper](https://www.drupal.org/project/vardumper) module.

Comment: Where should I look for `drupal_view` implementation? I've scoured all the Twig Tweak info I can find.

Comment: It's in the TwigExtension class but it just an alias of views_embed_view function.

Comment: `content.field_project_id` is, I believe, a render array for the field. A dump of that gets

 `array(1) { [0] => array(3) { '#type' => string(15) "inline_template" '#template' => string(17) "{{ value|nl2br }}" '#context' => array(1) { 'value' => string(14) "2011-40054-000" } } }`

If I put the literal into a var and dump that, it's just 

`string(14) "2011-40054-000"`.

The string works, the array doesn't. Seems that the function wants a string and doesn't know how to extract it from a render array, and I don't either.

Can you tell I'm kinda new to this stuff?

Comment: A view argument cannot be a render array for obvious reasons. If is a render array you can fetch the value but thats kind of quick dirty hack. The problem here is that you dont need to call for the view here, instead you should do it in a preprocess hook. But first where is your *content* var coming from? As it is an inline-template, typically this done by you or a contrib module as the core dont use that render element type quite often.

Answer (score 0):

You're treating {{ content }} as if it were an entity leveraging Entity API, but it's not - it's a render array.

It sounds like you're doing this in a node template, so you do actually have the entity as {{ node }} which is accessible using Entity API conventions. So this should probably work:

```
{{ drupal_view('my_view', 'block_1', node.field_project_id.value) }}
```